# database-first ef dbcontext scaffold translates Tablename to German

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have a postgres database where one table is named masterdata.
When I now run

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=xxx;Database=xxx;Username=xxx;Password=xxx" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Models -f
```

I get Entity Models which are named in "wrong" German.

The name is changed from `masterdata` to `Masterdatum`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Masterdatum>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("masterdata");
...
```

How can I switch off this behaviour? My System language is German. My VS language is English.

Comment: If you use EF Core 5, use --nopluralize option

Comment: @ErikEJ - Thanks that helps - but I still haven't got to link between "data" -> "datum" and pluralization...

Comment: This is bugging me too. Must be one of the rules applied during pluralization. Maybe we should open an issue with MS.

Comment: I have the same problem and cannot solve it.  Unfortunately, the problem has nothing to do with the German language.  Datum is the very, very uncommon singular form of data.  Please refer: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_(word) or https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/datum

Answer (score 1):

Like I already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280874/database-first-ef-dbcontext-scaffold-translates-tablename-to-german#comment125860745_66280874), this problem has nothing to do with the German language. To solve it you have to rename it manually because there is no configuration to inject without disabling the whole pluralization process. So you either have to create a script to rename the files and references on your own or you use the handlebars implementation of ef-scaffolding: `EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars`

Because it's a design-time service, you should put it into another namespace. In this service, you get the chance whenever a name is resolved to change this name:

```
namespace YourDatabaseProject.DesignTime
{
    public class ScaffoldingDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
    {
        public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddHandlebarsScaffolding(options =>
            {
                options.LanguageOptions = LanguageOptions.CSharp;
                options.EnableNullableReferenceTypes = true;
                options.EnableSchemaFolders = false;
            });

            serviceCollection.AddHandlebarsTransformers(
                entityNameTransformer: this.ReplaceUnwantedStrings,
                entityFileNameTransformer: this.ReplaceUnwantedStrings,
                propertyTransformer: propertyInfo => new EntityPropertyInfo(this.ReplaceUnwantedStrings(propertyInfo.PropertyType), propertyInfo.PropertyName, propertyInfo.PropertyIsNullable),
                navPropertyTransformer: propertyInfo => new EntityPropertyInfo(this.ReplaceUnwantedStrings(propertyInfo.PropertyType), propertyInfo.PropertyName, propertyInfo.PropertyIsNullable),
                constructorTransformer: propertyInfo => new EntityPropertyInfo(this.ReplaceUnwantedStrings(propertyInfo.PropertyType), propertyInfo.PropertyName, propertyInfo.PropertyIsNullable)
            );
        }

        private string? ReplaceUnwantedStrings(string? s)
        {
            return s?.Replace("Datum", "Data").Replace("datum", "data")
        }
    }
}
```

Now every time scaffold is executed this service renames `Datum` to `Data`.

Keep in mind that this code replaces `Datum` with `Data` in all type names. If you have a domain entity that contains `Datum`, because sometimes you don't want to translate very specific phases to English if you are not native, this will be renamed too. So it's not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal advice but you can screen the word "data" with something else. For example, instead of UserData table use UserData1 and you'll be alright.

Comment: Not an answer. Put it as commend under reaponse which you are responding and not separate.